# VBA Code doesn't want to identify a sub when its public

Tags: vba, ms-word, compiler-errors, subroutine

So this is probably a very basic question, but I am having difficulty figuring out why my VBA code will not call up the subroutine properly. Every time I try to run it it gives the compile error box saying expected sub. I have googled many different things and have tried converting the subroutine to a function but nothing is working.

BTW this code is supposed to calculate sin(x) the long way for an assignment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MainTest()
    Dim X As Double, Sum As Double, Y As Single, Term As Double, ERR As Long, M As Double, i As Single, Ans As Single
    
    Y = InputBox("Please enter the angle in degrees")
        X = Y * 3.14159 / 180
    ERR = InputBox("Please enter the maximum value for the last term in the series, suggested value is 10^-7")
    i = 1
    M = 1
    Sum = 0
    Do
       Call Term(i, X, Term)
       Sum = Sum + Term
       If (Abs(Term) < ERR) Then Exit Do
       i = i + 1
       M = M * (2 * i - 1)
    Loop
    
    Ans = Sin(Y)
    MsgBox (" sin(x) = " & Sum & " And the real is " & Ans)    
    
End Sub

Sub Term(ByVal i As Single, ByVal X As Single, ByRef Term As Long, ByVal M As Double)
    Term = (-1 ^ (i + 1) * X ^ (i - 1)) / M
    MsgBox ("Term is " & Term)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting this error. But it looks like you are calling a term subroutine with *three* arguments. You don't have any sub like that, because your Term sub takes *four* arguments.

Comment: Also I strongly urge you not to create a method call `Term()` and also use a variable call `Term` at the same time. VBA is probably not able to handle this. I.e., `Call Term(i, X, Term)` - is Term inside those parentheses supposed to be a variable or a method???

Comment: Instead of `Call Term(i, X, Term)` you possibly want to do `WriteTerm i, X, Term, M` obviously renaming the called procedure to `WriteTerm`. Also, using `ERR` is not recommended. Try e.g. `LastTerm` instead. InputBox has a `Default` argument, so you could add `Default:=0.0000001`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Your suggestions solved the problem.

Comment: Another mistake is that `Term` is a subroutine when it should be a function.